# How do I play a 4:3 video stretched to 16:9 on FFplay?

Tags: command-line, video, ffmpeg, playback

I want to play a 4:3 video stretched to 16:9 in FFplay. What is a command line for that?

Answer (score 0):

Basic form is

```
ffplay -i input -vf "setdar=16/9"
```